# Show textcursor before tapping

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using the TextField widget as a text input for my app. The text cursor starts blinking after I tap the TextField and doesn't stop blinking. What I would like to do is have the text cursor blink all the time. How do I have the text cursor start blinking before I even tap/activate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`autofocus`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/autofocus.html):

```
 TextField(
  autofocus  : true,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
  labelText: 'Name',
 ),
)
```

> Whether this text field should focus itself if nothing else is already focused.
> If true, the keyboard will open as soon as this text field obtains focus. Otherwise, the keyboard is only shown after the user taps the text field.
> Defaults to false. Cannot be null.